# Constructing a dependency list recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am trying to find if there is better way to do this recursion. I went through some examples of memoization but found myself struggling to implement that with my code.

example data: db_data and package_data

```
#input data
pack_data = {
    "depends_on": [{"id": "NF_PART_TWO", "type": "prep"}],
    "id": "NF_PART_ONE",
    "type": "prep",
}


#replaced db fetch by this data
db_data = [
    {
        "depends_on": [{"id": "NF_PART_THREE", "type": "prep"}],
        "id": "NF_PART_TWO",
        "type": "prep",
    },
    {
        "depends_on": [
            {"id": "NF_FIVE", "type": "mapping"},
            {"id": "NF_ZERO", "type": "prep"},
        ],
        "id": "NF_FOUR",
        "type": "mapping",
    },
    {
        "depends_on": [{"id": "NF_FOUR", "type": "prep"}],
        "id": "NF_PART_THREE",
        "type": "prep",
    },
    # when there is no dependency
    {
        "depends_on": [],
        "id": "NF_FIVE",
        "type": "transactional",
    },
    {"depends_on": [], "id": "NF_ZERO", "type": "prepbook"},
]



def get_down_deps(
    pack: dict, dependencies: Optional[List[dict]] = None, only_next=False
):

    dependencies = dependencies or [pack]
    output_dependencies = []
    for dep in dependencies:
        downstream_deps = [
            data
            for data in db_data
            if data["id"] in [val["id"] for val in dep["depends_on"]]
        ]

        if downstream_deps:

            output_dependencies.extend(
                get_down_deps(
                    pack=dep, dependencies=downstream_deps, only_next=only_next
                )
            )

        if not downstream_deps or not only_next:

            required = True

            dep_dict = {
                "depends_on": [val["id"] for val in dep["depends_on"]],
                "id": dep["id"],
                "required": required,
                "type": dep["type"],
            }
            output_dependencies.append(dep_dict)

    return output_dependencies


val = get_down_deps(pack_data)
print(val)
```

I would have liked to memoize the result of the recursive call, but didn't because I wasn't sure how to implement that.

Comment: @200_success, function indentation is getting messed up when pasting here. everything in for loop, if it is not clear.

Comment: Regarding your final sentence ("_I am stuck with ..._"): can you confirm that this code is finished and works as you want it?  It sounds like there's functionality that's not yet implemented (and would mean the code isn't yet ready to be reviewed).

Comment: @TobySpeight, this code is ready, it works fine. I just want to have memoized recursion, I am getting stuck when I try to do that because of expanding list. Currently it just simple recursion. I tried lru_cache but that will not work here.

Comment: It looks like DB fetches are occurring in the real code. Given that they are likely to be orders of magnitude slower than anything else your code is doing, why do you care about memoization? [It's also not clear to me why you have opted for  recursion for this use case, but that's a separate topic.]

Comment: @FMc, What would you recommend ?

Comment: I don't exactly know. It seems like you are concerned about performance (hence the interest in memoization), but your question seems(?) to omit what might be the most important aspect of the problem (the DB fetches). I guess my questions are coming from that uncertainty about what the real issues are. If performance is a primary concern, the key will be to optimize your DB interactions (eg don't re-query for the same entities); everything else will be trivial by comparison (at least in terms of raw performance).

Comment: A little elaboration: if re-querying for the same DB entities is a problem currently, maybe you should create a small memoized function that takes an ID (`data["id"]` in current code) and returns the needed entity. In other words, the thing that needs to be memoized is not `get_down_deps()` but the function that would talk to the DB. But that's just a guess on my part, since we don't know much about your real situation.